# Ruby Mechanize post doesn't work, but Node.JS Request post does

Tags: ruby, node.js, mechanize, http-post

I've been trying to make an interactive chat bot for a website, partially inspired by a friend who had already started to make one. They are making theirs in node.js, but I wanted to make mine in ruby since I'm more comfortable with it. However, after hours of debugging and trying new things I'm starting to think something is wrong with mechanize.

In node.js, I have installed `request` since that is what my friend uses to grab their page. Since ruby wasn't working at all, I decided I would make it in node.js and then transfer it over. Since the site owner wants bots to be private I won't go into specifics, but here is what I have.

Node.js

```
request.post({
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "bot",
        "Host": "example.com",
        "Referer": "http://example.com/",
        "X-CSRF-Token": token
    },
    url: "http://example.com/post",
    body: "channel=" + channel + "&action=post&data=" + message
}});
```

And this is the equivilent code in Ruby:

```
@agent.post("http://example.com/post", {
  "channel" => @channel,
  "action" => "post",
  "data" => message
},
{
  "User-Agent" => "bot",
  "Host" => "example.com",
  "X-CSRF-Token" => @csrf,
  "Referer" => "http://example.com/"
})
```

As far as I can tell, both of those post calls are identical but the site doesn't respond to the ruby script. The only thing that is required to send data is a session cookie and a special token, but checking mechanize's cookies show it is there. Is it not being sent in the post somehow? I'm really confused and have spent far too long trying to get this to work.

Edit:

I have tried to mimic the cookies from a proper response exactly, and although Fiddler says they're sending the same data it does not parse the ruby version.

Comment: Proxy the requests through fiddler and compare. One guess is because content-type header is missing.

Comment: @pguardiario I tried setting all the headers manually to mimic a manual entry and the ruby version still doesn't get parsed by the server.

Comment: There's some difference between the 2 requests. You need to compare them side by side to determine what that is. That's where Fiddler (or Charles) comes in.